# How to reshape an array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create 5*3 array like below without typing it explicitly.

```
[[1,  6, 11],
 [2,  7, 12],
 [3,  8, 13],
 [4,  9, 14],
 [5, 10, 15]]
```

I used write following codes.

```
np.arange(1, 16).T.reshape((5,3))
```

but it shows

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])
```

How can I order numbers in ascending order so that it becomes the first array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what you are looking for:

```
np.arange(1, 16).reshape((3,5)).T
```

In fact, in order:

- `np.arange(1,16)` will return evenly spaced values within the interval 1 to 6 (default step size is 1) [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html ];
- `.reshape((3,5))` is giving new shape to the previously formed array [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html ]. The new array will have 3 rows and 5 columns;
- `.T` will transpose the previously reshaped array [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html ]

Comment: Thank you! First creating 3 by 5 and transpose it. I got it.

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he/she would have come up with a similar solution on his/her own, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. As such, please provide context to your answer and/or code by explaining *how* and/or *why* it works.

Comment: @AlmightyR I have to disagree. Your comment can't be true for any question. This is a very specific question to a non-generic easy-to-understand problem, as it concerns an application of `numpy` methods. That also means that my answer, in terms of explanation, cannot add anything more than what people already would find in the documentation.

Comment: Ok then; let me make you a very simple question: Will a new programmer, who has never read about or used `.arange()` or `.reshape()` before, fully understand what is being done here, without having to look elsewhere? --- If your answer is "no", and I sincerely hope you are intellectually honest enough to come to that answer, then your answer *can* and *should* be improved, by providing, for example, a quick quote of the relevant part of the documentation of the methods, followed by or including the links. This would satisfy the contextualization of *"how"*, as of my previous comment.

Comment: If, however, you want to argue that *looking elsewhere* would be simple, then, ***I agree***, but then you've missed my point: If it's easy to get to the documentation, then *why not* at least briefly link it here, and *contextualize* your answer by doing so? Do you have any good reason to provide a contextually-incomplete answer that *some* (even if just a few) users might find confusing, instead of one that has complete context, and that all users can easily understand?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply. A noob won't fully understand what's being done here. I will be even more intellectually honest with you: many would probably not understand even a part of it. I have a couple of points, though. 1. I think SO serves many users at many different levels. If I read a question/answer I do not even understand, I would rather skip it and look back at the documentation to start to study and read thoroughly again - and that's because it is not for my level. This happens for questions like the one above. For some other type of questions I agree with you.

Comment: 2. With my answer users should not expect that I know all about `.numpy` [...and I don't]. I'm just giving my best answer here to help a user as much efficiently as possible [contextual completeness is not relevant for such question]. And I'm doing that for the exact reason you wrote on your first post: this is not wikipedia, where any user would act in a collaborative manner to create the best piece of answer.

Comment: Now that you read my opinion, I'll please you anyway, because I'm not a stubborn person and I think that giving a well explained answer is better than giving a too concise one.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, it is worth noticing that there is no need to transpose the array as suggested in the currently accepted answer. You just need to invoke [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) with the following arguments:

- `(5, 3)`, which corresponds to the positional parameter `newshape`, i.e. the shape of the array you wish to create.
- `order='F'`. The default value is `'C'`.

  Here is an excerpt from the **docs** on the `order` optional parameter:

  > ‘C’ means to read / write the elements using C-like index order, with the last axis index changing fastest, back to the first axis index changing slowest. ‘F’ means to read / write the elements using Fortran-like index order, with the first index changing fastest, and the last index changing slowest.

By doing so, the numbers are arranged column-wise:

```
In [45]: np.arange(1, 16).reshape((5, 3), order='F')
Out[45]: 
array([[ 1,  6, 11],
       [ 2,  7, 12],
       [ 3,  8, 13],
       [ 4,  9, 14],
       [ 5, 10, 15]])
```